# How to get array root and add to array child

Tags: php, arrays

How do I take the root of an array and then add into the value taken his child to become an array of array data

I have an array data like :

```
array(10) {
  ["2016-07-06"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(795)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(896)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3134)
  }
  ["2016-07-07"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(878)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(987)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3975)
  }
}
```

From the data array above I would like to take in the array of arrays where I want to combine the date data into their array.

Let's just above my input array into a single variable. Call it `$allData`. Then I loop

```
foreach ($allData as $data) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($data);
}
```

From the results above loop I get a new array data like

```
array(11) {
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(795)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(896)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3134)
}
array(11) {
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(878)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(987)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3975)
}
```

If I want to take the data that previously used the root array `array_push()`, how to take and put it to use `array_push()`?

Formed later so that the end result as

```
array(11) {
    ["date_visitor"]=>
    string(20) "2016-07-06"
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(795)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(896)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3134)
}
array(11) {
    ["date_visitor"]=>
    string(20) "2016-07-07"
    ["nb_uniq_visitors"]=>
    int(878)
    ["nb_users"]=>
    int(0)
    ["nb_visits"]=>
    int(987)
    ["nb_actions"]=>
    int(3975)
}
```

Using what functions to take root array, then I will use array_push to add the data into an array of child?

Thanks

Comment: Can the downvoter please care to comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach loop should do the job:

```
$new=[];
foreach($allData as $key=>$value){
    $value['date_visitor']=$key;
    $new[]=$value;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve for your help